# How to put a ListView inside a Fragment?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a fragment with a listview inside it where I will put some data from api. I know how to do when I use activity.

I've create a base adapter and in my fragment I have something like this:

```
    Transactions_weekly transactions;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weekly_datas, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.weekly_data_list);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        transactions = (Transactions_weekly) intent.getSerializableExtra("transactions");
        Transaction_Weekly_Adapter adapter = new Transaction_Weekly_Adapter(this, transactions);
        ArrayAdapter<Transactions_weekly> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                Collections.singletonList(transactions));
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        return  view;
}
```

The problem is in these two lines:
`Intent intent = getIntent();`saying cannot resolve method getIntent() and
`Transaction_Weekly_Adapter adapter = new Transaction_Weekly_Adapter(this, transactions);`

Any help is appreciated
!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 1- getActivity().getIntent();

 2- Transaction_Weekly_Adapter adapter = new Transaction_Weekly_Adapter(getActivity(), transactions);
```

hope to help !

Answer (score 0):

`Intent` is held by your activity. Try `Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();`. This may fix your problem with the `adapter` variable too, but I notice that you never use that variable and create an `arrayAdapter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can access intent by using container activity so you should to use **getActivity** method to be able to access Intent

```
getActivity().getIntent();
```